# Reset remote tracked branch

Tags: git

How can I reset the branch pointer of a remote tracked branch to one of its previous commits, so it looks like I didn't pulled (something similar like reset hard for local branches)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the reference to any other commit with:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master <commit-sha1 or tag>
```

This will make remote branch `origin/master` point to the commit you specified.